# iOS 7 navigation bar visual glitch when transitioning between view controllers

Tags: ios, ios7, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uikit

I've got a very simple setup using segues to display a simple master/details configuration. When pushing or popping from the navigation controller, the right hand side of the navigation bar has a strange grey shadow. See [this video](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/26701901/ios7-nav-bar-glitch.mp4) for a demo.

[image]

If I remove all subviews from the detail controller and simply set the background as red (see [video](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/26701901/ios7-nav-bar-glitch-1.mov)), I still get the grey artefact, and strangely, the red only appears behind the navigation bar once the entire transition has finished.

Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

Well, very strange, but simply deleting and re-creating an identical view controller in the storyboard fixed this issue.

Comment: Bugs in Xcode 6 abound... Was having a weird constraints issue that was fixed simply by deleting and recreating the view.